# Replacing values in array with decimals

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have an array `arr100 = np.ones(100)`. I need to replace these values with decimals,
where `arr100[0]` has a value `1`, `arr100[1] = 1/2`, `arr100[2] = 1/3`,
and so on until `arr100[99] = 1/100`.

How to do this using a `for` loop in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
arr100 = np.ones(100)
for n in range(1, 101):
    arr100[n-1] /= n
```

which changes `arr100` to:

```
array([1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333, 0.25      , 0.2       ,
       0.16666667, 0.14285714, 0.125     , 0.11111111, 0.1       ,
[....]
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need an imported module (numpy) to do this. It can be done in a natural python list.

so you can just do this:

```py
result = [1/(i+1) for i in range(100)]
print(result)
```

which returns this:

```
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.14285714285714285, 0.125, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1, 0.09090909090909091, 0.08333333333333333, 0.07692307692307693, 0.07142857142857142, 0.06666666666666667, 0.0625, 0.058823529411764705, 0.05555555555555555, 0.05263157894736842, 0.05, 0.047619047619047616, 0.045454545454545456, 0.043478260869565216, 0.041666666666666664, 0.04, 0.038461538461538464, 0.037037037037037035, 0.03571428571428571, 0.034482758620689655, 0.03333333333333333, 0.03225806451612903, 0.03125, 0.030303030303030304, 0.029411764705882353, 0.02857142857142857, 0.027777777777777776, 0.02702702702702703, 0.02631578947368421, 0.02564102564102564, 0.025, 0.024390243902439025, 0.023809523809523808, 0.023255813953488372, 0.022727272727272728, 0.022222222222222223, 0.021739130434782608, 0.02127659574468085, 0.020833333333333332, 0.02040816326530612, 0.02, 0.0196078431372549, 0.019230769230769232, 0.018867924528301886, 0.018518518518518517, 0.01818181818181818, 0.017857142857142856, 0.017543859649122806, 0.017241379310344827, 0.01694915254237288, 0.016666666666666666, 0.01639344262295082, 0.016129032258064516, 0.015873015873015872, 0.015625, 0.015384615384615385, 0.015151515151515152, 0.014925373134328358, 0.014705882352941176, 0.014492753623188406, 0.014285714285714285, 0.014084507042253521, 0.013888888888888888, 0.0136986301369863, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013333333333333334, 0.013157894736842105, 0.012987012987012988, 0.01282051282051282, 0.012658227848101266, 0.0125, 0.012345679012345678, 0.012195121951219513, 0.012048192771084338, 0.011904761904761904, 0.011764705882352941, 0.011627906976744186, 0.011494252873563218, 0.011363636363636364, 0.011235955056179775, 0.011111111111111112, 0.01098901098901099, 0.010869565217391304, 0.010752688172043012, 0.010638297872340425, 0.010526315789473684, 0.010416666666666666, 0.010309278350515464, 0.01020408163265306, 0.010101010101010102, 0.01]
```

or you could do this to get the same:

```py
import numpy as np

arr100 = np.ones(100)

for i,j in enumerate(arr100):
    arr100[i] = 1/(i+1)

print(arr100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(101):
    arr100[i] = 1/arr100[i]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.